# Saving web page as an html file on computer

Tags: html, http, web, httprequest, diff

I want to save the source code for my website page into my computer. I know that I have to use an http request to download the source code for my web page into the computer as a html file. I want to run a diff to track changes between two html files for a web page. I am wondering how to implement a program to perform the function of saving a web page as an html file on my computer. Please help it is really appreciated. I want to solve the problem programatically. I was researching on this topic and found that httpget, and selenium scripts can achieve this task but I am struggling with the implementation.

Comment: Programmatically or manually? If you go to the website in a browser then there is almost always a way to view source. Usually right click 'view source'. Then just copy and paste.

Comment: Programmatically Do you have any ideas about the implementation? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you with your code, you must show us the code you've tried (even if it's broken). we can't help you fix it by just a description. Please *edit your question* and add the code there (don't put code in comments)

Answer (score 0):

With linux you can just use wget.

```
wget http://google.com
```

that will save a file called index.html on your computer.

Programmatically you can use python:

```
import urllib2

# create a list of urls that you want to download
urls = ['http://example.com', 'http://google.com']

# loop over the urls
for url in urls:
    # make the request
    request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    # make the filename valid (you can change this to suit your needs)
    filename = url.replace('http://', '')
    filename = filename.replace('/','-')
    # write it to a file.
    with open(filename + '.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(request.read())
```